# Laravel array shows as null before data array

Tags: laravel

I have a user that has many properties. This is user should also be able tp view the offers bet on his properties.

So  have the relationship set.

User.php

```
public function properties(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Property');
}
```

Property.php

```
public function offers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}
```

Then in my controller this is what I have:

```
public function my_offers(){

    $properties = Property::whereUserId(Auth::id())->get();


    return view('pages.seller.offers.index', compact('properties'));
}
```

Then I go to my views like this:

```
@if($properties)
<ul>
    @foreach($properties as $property)

        <li>{{$property->offers->offer_message}}</li>

    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

When I view the page I see the below error:

Property [offer_message] does not exist on this collection instance.

But this property exists in my table.

If I change my list item to the one below I can see the array:

```
 <li>{{$property->offers}}</li>
```

I also see that before and after the array with the data, there are two empty arrays as the image shows below:

[image]

Is there anything that I didn't correctly?

Comment: Well, it seems that not all the properties have offers. Is that something you would expect?

Comment: No, not all properties have offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not all the properties have offers, then you should check that before the `<li>`, besides that, `offers` is a collection, you need to loop through it, that's why you get the error.

```
@if($properties)
@php ($i = 1)
<ul>
    @foreach($properties as $property)
        @if ($property->offers)
            @foreach ($property->offers as $offer)
                <li>Offer {{ $i++ }}: {{$offer->offer_message}}</li>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

If you want to get only de properties that have offers ([Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)):

```
$properties = Property::whereUserId(Auth::id())->has('offers')->get();
```

And you should probably [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) that relationship:

```
$properties = Property::whereUserId(Auth::id())->has('offers')->with('offers')->get();
```

Comment: See my edit. "Offers" is a collection, you need to loop through it.

Comment: Giiz. I am definetely taking note for this. It works now and I really appreciate the support

Comment: Just in addition to that. How can I number them. Say if I have 3 offers, then system should say "Offer 1", "Offer 2" and so on

Comment: Glad I could help. If you keep the `has('offers')`, then you could remove the `if ($property->offers)`. You need to number them within each property? I mean, when you loop through a new property, the count should start from 1 again or not? This could help you: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: Yes I do need to number them accordingly